# How to keep scrolling position in ScrollView after rotating the screen in fragment with LiveDate object loaded

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-scrollview, android-livedata

I have a fragment which is to display a lyrics of a song which is loaded from room databse based on its given id.

I'd like to preserve scrolling position after rotating the screen. Now after rotating the song is loaded again from db and the view is on the very top regardless of the scrolling position befor the rotating.

I thought that I can save scrolling position in `onSaveInstanceState` some bundle in `onCreateView()` use command on `mSongDisplayScrollView.scrollTo(x, y)`

The fragment code:

```java
public class SongDisplayFragment extends Fragment {

    private Song mSongToDisplay;

    private ScrollView mSongDisplayScrollView;
    private TextView mSongTitleTextView;
    private RecyclerView mSongLyricsRecyclerView;

    private GuitarSongbookViewModel mGuitarSongbookViewModel;

    public static final String SONG_ID_KEY = "SONG_ID_KEY";


    public SongDisplayFragment() {

    }

    public static SongDisplayFragment newInstance(Long songId) {
        SongDisplayFragment songDisplayFragment = new SongDisplayFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putLong(SONG_ID_KEY, 
        songDisplayFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return songDisplayFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_display, container, false);

        mSongDisplayScrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.song_display_scroll_view);
        mSongLyricsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.lyrics_rv_);
        mSongTitleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.

        mGuitarSongbookViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GuitarSongbookViewModel.class);

        final SongDisplayAdapter songDisplayAdapter = new SongDisplayAdapter(getContext());

        Long songId = null;
        if (getArguments().containsKey(SONG_ID_KEY)) {
            songId = getArguments().getLong(SONG_ID_KEY);
        }

        if (songId != null) {
            final Long finalSongId = songId;


            mGuitarSongbookViewModel.getSongById(songId).observe(this, new Observer<Song>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final Song song) {
                    mSongToDisplay = song;
                    mSongTitleTextView.setText(mSongToDisplay.getMTitle());
                    songDisplayAdapter.setSong(song);

                }
            });


        }


        mSongLyricsRecyclerView.setAdapter(songDisplayAdapter);
        mSongLyricsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return view;
    }

}
```

The fragment XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SongDisplayFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/song_display_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/autoscroll_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="138dp">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/son_display_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/displayed_song_title_txt_"
                style="@style/TitleOfDisplayedSong"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/title_placeholder" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/lyrics_rv_"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragment displays a tiltle and lyrics of a song in a textView and RecyclerView which adapter class code is:

```java
package com.example.guitarsongbook.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.guitarsongbook.R;
import com.example.guitarsongbook.daos.SongChordJoinDao;
import com.example.guitarsongbook.model.Chord;
import com.example.guitarsongbook.model.Song;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SongDisplayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongDisplayAdapter.SongViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private Song mSong;
    private ArrayList<String> mLyrics;

    public SongDisplayAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SongViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.song_lyrics_rv_item, parent, false);
        return new SongDisplayAdapter.SongViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public void setSong(Song song){
        mSong = song;
        mLyrics = mSong.getMLyrics();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindTo(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mLyrics != null)
            return mLyrics.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    public class SongViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView mLyricsLineTextView;


        public SongViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mLyricsLineTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_lyric_line_txt_);
        }

        public void bindTo(int position) {
            if (mSong != null) {
                mLyricsLineTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mLyrics.get(position)));



            } else {
                mLyricsLineTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.no_song_label));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

RecyclerView item XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_lyric_line_txt_"
        style="@style/LyricOfDisplayedSong"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/song_chord_line_txt_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="placeholder text" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think that the problem is that after rotating the screen song has to be loaded again by observer's methon `onChange()` so there is a short moment that there is nothing to display for scrollView. I'd like to find some solution how to return to the old position after again loading the song.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to persist the values of the objects through your Fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` method.

More of my explanations would come from the comments within each code block, so you can understand better on how it all works.

> Values to be persisted: **mSongToDisplay** and **mScrollViewPosition**

```
//new variable introduced
int mScrollViewPosition = 0;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //If screen orientation changes, android redraws all views 
    //and non persistent data would be lost. 
    //Nevertheless, before this happens android informs the app via this method
    //So to prevent state loss we save the data to a temporary storage
     outState.putParcelable("song_data", mSongToDisplay);
    //save ScrollView current position
     outState.putInt("position_data", mSongDisplayScrollView.getScrollY());
    //call super to commit your changes 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Next is to recover the data after orientation change is completed

Add the following block in your `fragments onCreateView` and make sure the `if statement block` comes after initializing your adapter

```
 ...
 //...add adapter initialization block here before checking for saved data 

 //Check for saved data
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  // Retrieve the data you saved
  mSongToDisplay = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("song_data");
  mScrollViewPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position_data");

  //Re-initialize and reload adapter record
  mSongToDisplay = song;
  mSongTitleTextView.setText(mSongToDisplay.getMTitle());
  songDisplayAdapter.setSong(song); 
 } 
 else {
 //No data to retrieve
 //initialize data model here. 
 }

   //Assign the adapter to recyclerView
   mSongLyricsRecyclerView.setAdapter(songDisplayAdapter);
   mSongLyricsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
  try{
   //Finally we set the scrollview position at this point just to make sure
   //recyclerview has its data loaded and full length of scrollview is restored
   mSongDisplayScrollView.setScrollY(mScrollViewPosition);}
  catch(Exception ex){
     //position isn't right
   }
  return view;
```

At this point the required data has been persisted and on every `screenOrientationChange` the app would load the previously saved song object into the adapter preventing a false call to the `db or api`, and would also scroll to the expected position using the saved integer value `mScrollViewPosition`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working but only a little. I mean that now after roatating the screen, the song is very quickly reloaded but the view is scrolled only to the very beginning of the neseted recyclerView. So it doesn't matter how far I scroll a lyrics of song after rotating it will be displayed at it beginning. 

It must be somehow connected with that there is recyclerView inside scrollView but I don't want to scroll using recyclerView ony with scrollView.

Comment: I got it working using this snippet in `onCreateView()`
`if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            final int scrollY = savedInstanceState.getInt("position_data");

            mSongDisplayScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSongDisplayScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
                }
            },700);

        }`
But the drawback is that it is not smooth because there is moment when it has to jump to demanded position.

Comment: Looking at XY coordinates and storing, retrieving after rotation won't work because there's no guarantee word wrapping is going to happen the same way in portrait and landscape modes. The Y coord for some item might be double or triple in portrait vs landscape depending on your screen ratio, etc.